# How to get RBAC roles assigned to my service principal from PowerShell/CLI/REST API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, command-line-interface, azure-service-principal

I have service principal where I assigned multiple roles to it which are required in accessing Azure resources by doing user_impersonation.

Now I want to get these list of roles from Powershell/CLI/REST API.

I'm finding documents for fetching appRoleAssignments of service principal using MS graph :

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/00063ffc-54e9-405d-b8f3-56124728e051/appRoleAssignedTo
```

But that is not what I need. Are there any existing commands that helps me to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

check out this link:

[Get-Azroleassignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-9.1.0#examples)

Updating my answer with Powershell:

```
$spn = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "your spn display name"
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectID $spn.id
```

Also, you must have an atleast active directory reader access to execute this command successfully.

Comment: @Rich - Its good to know.